# Function can't be called when using backtick notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Below is a code snippet for adding stuff dynamically

```
document.getElementById('classTbody').innerHTML+=`
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            ${doc.data().course}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            ${doc.data().dateTime}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            ${doc.data().classLocation}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="#" class="text-muted">
                              View Attendance
                            </a>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="deleteClass('${data}','${classesDoc[i]}')" class="text-muted">
                              Delete
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>`
```

The deleteClass function is added in the same script block as below

```
 function deleteClass(id,docID){
          const user = auth.currentUser;
          try{
            deleteDoc(doc(db,"lecturer",user.uid,"classCreated",docID))
            deleteDoc(doc(db,"class",id))
            alert('Class Deleted')
            setTimeout(function() {
              location.reload();
            }, 500);
          }
          catch(e){
            alert("Something went wrong!")
          }
      }
```

But when I click delete I am getting this error,  
Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteClass is not defined.  
 
It only works when I put the function in a different script block. But I need to put it in the same block to get access to Firebase's methods. 
Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Because it would need to be in global scope for the HTML to see it.

Comment: I kinda understand it now, but when I declare the function globally I won't be able to use Firebase's methods, anyway to solve it?

Comment: Hard to see what the issue is without seeing more code. Personally my solution would be to not use inline event handler and just use event delegation.

Comment: Please Consider Formatting Your Code When Posting, Explaining The Problem In Detail & Including The Exact Error / Stack Trace In Your Question To Help Others Understand It Easily.